# Strange text with Wygwam

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam, expresso-toolbar

I update a site to EE2.7.2 and Wygwam to 3.2.1. When I copy text form Open Office and paste it as plain text in Wygwam I always get this "extra" text at the top:

Version:1.0 StartHTML:0000000167 EndHTML:0000000922 StartFragment:0000000454 EndFragment:0000000906

When I was using EE2.5.3 with Wygwam 2.6.3 I never got this strange text.

Francois

Comment: What happens if you "Paste from Word" instead (even though you aren't using Word)?

Comment: I just did it, get the same.

Comment: Not sure, then. Hopefully, someone else and/or Pixel and Tonic can help you out.

Comment: I just install a new ee2.7 but this time with expresso and I get the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the WYGWAM Edit Configuration page for that particular WYGWAM config, and chose under Advanced Settings > forcePasteAsPlainText AND pasteFromWordRemoveStyles? That they're both set to Yes?

However, doing this means EVERY copy-paste you ever do from wherever will be copy-pasted as plain text.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in last update from CKEditor. I get the same problem, when I copy and paste text from OpenOffice, with their demo site: http://ckeditor.com/demo